# How to integrate ActiveMQ with Dell Boomi

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic, integration, boomi

I have a tough time integrating the ActiveMQ using Dell Boomi as the Dell Boomi documentation is old and may be misleading too sometimes. As I could not find a good suggestion on the web I am putting my query here. Can someone please help with the steps of how to integrate ActiveMQ with Boomi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below steps I got it working--

1. Copy activemq-core-5.4.3.jar and geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar files from your ActiveMQ to your Atom/usrlib/database (create if not there)  directory.
2. Create a jndi property file and place in ActiveMQ home directory. [Reference this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/resources/jndi.properties).

You might get NoClassDefFound error for JMS/Topic etc, means your Boomi lib does not have the implementation for that. You need to copy activemq-all-5.4.3.jar from ActiveMQ home folder to Atom/lib.

I am not specifying how to create JMS Connection and Operation in boomi however, below properties you can use for **JMS conneciton** in Boomi--

1. Connection Factory JNDI Lookup: ConnectionFactory.
2. Initial Context Factory: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory (default).
3. Provider URL: tcp://localhost:61616 (Default port).

**JMS Operation--**

Destination : dynamicQueues/Dell_Boomi (Dynamic will create a queue if not existing).

That's all, try your luck and share your experience!

Answer (score 1):

pick

```
jars activemq-client,hawtbuf,geronimo-jms_1.1_spec,geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec
```

from the `lib\plugin\queue` and copy it to the lib folder. Restart Atom and it should work now.